# How to convert a genericValue to Value in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I'm working in interpreter. I have the address of a variable in memory and I managed to get the real value form it and put it in a genericValue using LoadValueFromMemory function. Now I need to create a StoreInst and want to put this value got in a Value object to use it in the StoreInst. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title, `GenericValue` is just a type-agnostic container for some value. To create an LLVM `Value` from it, you need to create a [`Constant`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Constant.html) of the appropriate type, and use that value to initialize the constant.

I'm assuming you are referring to getting a value from one module and using it in another unrelated module, otherwise it's not clear to me why you pass through a `GenericValue` for this:

- If the value came from the interpreter side, you don't need to store it in a `GenericValue`, you can just create a `Constant` from that value.
- If the value came from the LLVM IR side in the same module, you also don't need to load that `Value` into a `GenericValue`, you can just use that `Value` directly as the argument when creating the `store` instruction.

Comment: the value I have in interpreter is a pointer to memory location. I could not get it directly without loading it from memory first. And  I could not find a way but to use LoadValueFromMemory function, which store the loaded value into genericValue. 
And I already made a constantInt and created value from the genericValue I have. However when I try to create storeInst from this value I get this error:
void llvm::StoreInst::AssertOK(): Assertion `getOperand(0)->getType() == cast<PointerType>(getOperand(1)->getType())->getElementType() && "Ptr must be a pointer to Val type!"' failed.

Comment: Actually, finally it worked. The problem was in AllocaInst itself, not anything else. I use using a pointer to int as the type of alloca instead of using int. It worked now finally. Thanks.