# Converting from GenericValue to Value* in setOperand

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm using interpreter. I need to convert `GenericValue` to `Value *` in function `setOperand`. For example,

```
GenericValue newV;
I.setOperand(0, (Value*)newV);
```

I'm inserting some results in `newV`, then I need to insert it to a certain instruction as example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a genericValue to Value in LLVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807875/how-to-convert-a-genericvalue-to-value-in-llvm)