# What is LLVM's GenericValue for?

Tags: llvm

I’m trying to figure out the data structures used for partial interpretation of LLVM intermediate code, and noticing that GenericValue is a container for a value of arbitrary type. But as I understand it, the same could also be said of ConstantExpr. What exactly does GenericValue do, that ConstantExpr does not? The closest I have found to existing discussion of the matter is [How to convert a genericValue to Value in LLVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807875/how-to-convert-a-genericvalue-to-value-in-llvm) the answer to which describes a couple of situations in which you do not need to use GenericValue, but none in which you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ConstantExpr is a constant expression that exists within the program being compiled (or in a JIT, the VM where the code is run). It's distant from the code in the compiler — you need quite a bit of code if you want to check whether a ConstantExpr ≥42, but emitting code to check ≥42 is dead easy.

A GenericValue, on the other hand, is a compiletime thing. Testing whether it's ≥42 is easy (and has a ternary result), but on the other hand generating code to check ≥42 at runtime is hard.

There's a lot of this in compilering. Some things exist within the compiler, others exist within the output, and even though the two can be confusingly similar there's a world of difference. Trying to share code or concepts among the two universes always leads to pain, there are always little details that spoil everything at the last minute. (Just think about how you'd prevent sandbox escapes if the compiler's address space were shared with untrusted JITted code.)